# Find all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy both $\frac{3x-4y}{xy} = -8$ and $\frac{2x+7y}{xy} = 43$

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

The following is listed under the "multiple variable" category of my Algebra I homework.

> Find all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ that satisfy both $\frac{3x-4y}{xy} = -8$ and $\frac{2x+7y}{xy} = 43$

I can't wrap my head around what to do. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Note this is a pair of linear equations in $1/x,1/y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{3x-4y}{xy} = \frac{3}{y} - \frac{4}{x} = -8$$

$$\frac{2x+7y}{xy} = \frac{2}{y}+\frac{7}{x} = 43$$

Let $u = \frac{1}{x}$ and $v = \frac{1}{y}$.

Then,

> $3v - 4u = -8$  and $2v + 7u = 43$

Solve these linear equations and replace $x$ and $y$.